# How to publish android library to subversion and use it on projects

Tags: android, svn, aar

There are many posts about publishing android library in github. Is there any way to publish android library to the svn?

EDIT:
I have created a libray and build the aar file. I have imported the aar file in to a tag of the svn. (Ex: svnpath/project/tags/library0.0.1.aar)
I want to use this library in a separate project. I want to use this library as

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
```

like this. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Yes. `VCS > Import into version control > Import into subversion...`

Comment: I'm guessing this question is about using SVN as your versioning tool of choice rather than Git? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: Seems like question is not clear. I will update the question

Comment: Depends if you want to make the .aar public or keep it private. If you want to keep it private to yourself, you'll need to create your own Maven repository, possibly using a tool like Artifactory. Unfortunately that answer would be a bit broad for SO, and I don't know enough about it to answer myself, but there's plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: instead of using maven can't we use svn?

Comment: I think you're confusing the purpose of SVN. SVN is a **version control** tool for source code (much like Git), allowing you to keep track of different branches and revisions of your code. Maven is a **dependency management** system, allowing you to pull in libraries and other dependencies from external sources. SVN isn't an appropriate tool for what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. Now i understand.

Comment: There is a nifty little tool called `Jitpack` that you can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, Subversion (SVN) is not an appropriate tool for what you are trying to achieve. Subversion is a **version control** system which manages the versioning of source code files and associated resources, much in the same manner as Git does.

What you are looking for is a **dependency management** system using Maven, for example Artifactory. This will allow you to publish your .aar files to either a public-facing or private repository and import those dependencies into your `build.gradle` file. Unfortunately the process for setting up such a service is too broad for the scope of this question, but once you have it up and running you can add it to your `build.gradle` file under the `repositories` section:

```
repositories {
    maven {
         url "<url of Maven server>"
         credentials {
              // If you choose to use authentication
              username = <your artifactory username>
              password = <your artifactory password>
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Micheal Dodd. As you suggested i used my local maven repository to achieve this.